# Cmd not closing after running a SQL file using a bat file

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I'm trying to run a SQL file using a bat file and also printing the output from the SQL file in a text file using this bat script.

```
@echo off
sqlplus username/password@dbname @filename.sql > output.txt
exit
```

I entered the username, password, dbname and filename with appropriate values.
When I run the bat file I'm getting the proper output in the text file.
But the cmd is not closing by itself.

I had to close the cmd manually everytime I run the bat file.
Is there any other way to make the cmd close by itself?

Comment: Does the SQL file explicitly exit the database connection?

Comment: What about just a one line script: ```@start sqlplus username/password@dbname @filename.sql > output.txt```?

Comment: Just use EXIT 0 at the end

Comment: @Compo the output is not getting printed in a text file if i use the script you suggested.

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya the cmd is not closing even after using exit 0 at the end

Comment: @pmdba how to make it exit? I'm running a simple select query in the SQL file, any modifications I need to do which will allow to exit the database connection?

Comment: There should be an `exit` command in the SQL file, otherwise you'll just come to a SQL prompt and stop. The shell script never exits because the `sqplus` call never exits.

Comment: If the command I gave you is not working as intended, the most likely reason is that you have doublquotes in it, and did not indicate that to us. Please post a more representative example of your actual command.

Comment: @Compo I didn't used any double quotes, I used the one line script that you gave as it is, I'm getting the output in the cmd window but not in the text file.

Comment: @ArunMadhunala, there is no difference between my suggeted command and the second line of your code, (other than the use of the `start` command, which runs `sqlplus` as a detached process, _from the batch-file_). If the output redirection handle, `>` , (technically `1>`), works in your command line, then it must in mine, given your above comment. It may be worth mentioning however, that the stdOut may not propagate the output file until the `sqlplus` has completed. It seems most likely therefore that your `sqlplus` executable has/is not completing. That has nothing to do with cmd/batch though.

Comment: Using the keyword "quit;" in the SQL file allowed to return to the cmd, now the cmd is closing with the exit keyword and I'm getting the proper output. Thanks everyone for your time. Thank you.

Comment: So, now you can change the batch file to the single line I offered earlier!